# Bing Maps CalculateRoute based on Coordinates

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am using the **Bing Maps API** in order to draw the route between my current position and some coordinate defined point on map and get the directions.

I found an example on [Microsoft Developer Network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/WP7TrainingCourse_UsingBingMapsLab) implementing this functionality based on the name of the two locations not the coordinates.

I found online that there is such an interface called **SimpleRouteCalculator**, anyone aware of this class?? help plz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Bing Maps Directions Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394024%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) launcher. It allows you to specify a GeoLocation as Start- end Endpoint.

It's available from Windows Phone 7.1 (Mango).